# Vote to close - off-topic descriptions are wrong

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Clicking to close a question as 'off topic' gives a list of off-topic reasons but the 'belongs on...' descriptions all say "Q&A for professional and independent game developers" ...

[image: belongs on]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this

Comment: Yes, it's certainly not happening on my work PC (windows 7, Firefox 3.6.13). I will try it again on my laptop (Fedora 14, Firefox 3.6.13) which is in another office. I won't be able to do this until about 1900 UTC so perhaps leave this open until I report back?

Comment: OK - can't now reproduce on Fedora/Firefox so time to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see invalid close reasons on Super User - this might have been an artifact of earlier builds for some [search improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out).

Comment: Accepted because before this happened the site was down for maintenance so whatever was being done might have had after effects due to caching or..I dunno, but I can't reproduce the problem now.